# Android - language of onscreen keyboard

Tags: android, on-screen-keyboard

In system I have defined 3 different keyboards (Czech, Slovak, Russia) and I want to switch between them programmatically without calling InputMethodManager.showInputMethodPicker(), because it show the selector, which I don't want.
How to do it? Please for Android 10 system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, for example, switch onscreen keyboard layout to Slovakia at runtime, in kotlin:

```
myEditText.imeHintLocales = LocaleList(Locale("sk", "SK"))
```

Comment: It works but is up to the keyboard to support this and many do not. It works with the current Gboard though.